# JS is not loaded while linking the Home page on Logo in NextJS

Tags: next.js

When i run on load then all js file are loaded but when i am trying to put an home page link on company's logo at that time js is not loaded in  NextJs.

Please check the screenshot for further details

on load image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaHBj.png)

when use link image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JVpT.png)
Code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtGNv.png)

Thank you

Comment: Provide the images and code directly into the post.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JVpT.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/4JVpT.png